# Dispatch ctrl+click event

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

How can I dispatch a ctrl+click event?
I'm scraping a webpage and there are no `<a></a>` tags, just `<div></div>` tags with click events in `.js` file and they open in another instance of the web browser.
I want to open in the same instance but in a new tab, so dispatching a ctrl+click should do the trick.

Comment: Why don't you want to use `a` tag?

Comment: Yes, it did answer my question. Thank you! @MatthiasThalmann